# Characterization of finite nilpotent groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Can someone please check my proof of the following "evident" equivalence stated in Kurzweil and Stellmacher.

> A finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $$U<N(U) \text{ whenever } U<G.$$

**My attempt:** First suppose that $G$ is nilpotent. Then by definition, every subgroup is subnormal. Let $U<G$. By subnormality, we can find $U_1,\ldots, U_d\leq G$ such that $$U=U_1\triangleleft U_2\triangleleft\ldots \triangleleft U_d=G.$$
Now because $U\neq G$, there exists $y_d\in G=U_d\setminus U$. Therefore $y_d^{-1} U_{d-1} y_d=U_{d-1}$. Similarly, there exists $y_{d-1}\in U_{d-1}\setminus U_{d-1}$ such that $y_{d-1}^{-1} U_{d-2} y_{d-1}=U_{d-2}$.
Continuing this way, there exists $y_2\in U_2\setminus U_1=U$ such that $y_2^{-1}Uy_2=U$ and so $y_2\in N(U)\setminus U$, which completes this part.

Conversely, assume that $$U<N(U) \text{ whenever } U<G.$$ Since every subgroup is normal in its normaliser, we have $U\triangleleft N(U)$. If $N(U)=G$, we're done. Otherwise, $$U\triangleleft N(U)\triangleleft N(N(U)).$$ Continuing this way, we get $$U\triangleleft N(U)\triangleleft N(N(U))\triangleleft \ldots \triangleleft G$$ and this series must be finite because $G$ is finite.

Comment: You are assuming that every subgroup of a finite nilpotent group  is subnormal. This requires a proof, because the usual definition of a nilpotent group often is   different. For an "easy" direct proof without this assumption of one direction see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Nilpotent_implies_normalizer_condition&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop) for example.

Comment: I find the downvote here quite strange. This is high quality question with a clear attempt.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually, as I mentioned that I'm following Kurzweil and Stellmacher. That is their definition of nilpotent groups. Hence I wrote "by definition" in my proof.

Comment: Alright, then the proof is straightforward. The condition that $U<N(U)$ is strictly smaller for all proper subgroups $U<G$ is called *normalizer condition*. Perhaps you should make clear all symbols $U<G$, $U\le G$, $U\triangleleft G$ and $U \trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So is my proof correct? Specially the last part?

Comment: Where did you use that $U\lneqq N(U)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde To write $U\triangleleft N(U)$ instead of $U\trianglelefteq N(U)$.

Comment: I see. Some people use $U\triangleleft G$ to include $U=G$, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I know but I follow the notation of Kurzweil and Stellmacher. Can you tell me if my proof is correct?

Comment: What doubts do you have "specially the last part"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Whether, "continuing this way, this series must be finite" is precise enough or whether it needs to be argued more? Also, whether rest of the proof is correct.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I also think that the last part actually shows that every finite group is nilpotent? I'm really confused. Please help.

Comment: But your argument has used the normalizer condition, i.e., that $U\neq N(U)$ for this. This doesn't hold for every finite group.

Comment: Right, I finally got it. Thank you!